# Using etags with cursors while retrieving paged data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, etag, facebook-ads-api

With migration of Ads API to v2 ability to retrieve pages of using offset, limit and count is removed. Instead of this cursors are coming into first place.

In the past it was enough to store request and it's etag - URL of next page is easily calculated based on it's number. With migration to cursors it becomes impossible and seems cursor to next page also needs to be stored together with etag, so that if page (etag) haven't changed, next page can be retrieved with cursor stored last time page was retrieved.

It also becomes impossible to retrieve pages in parallel as values of cursors are not known in advance - it's only possible to retrieve page by page in sequence.

Does anyone has experience with etags and cursors? What is best practice in this area?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that once the cursor has been generated, the contents will not change. If the contents of the page does change then the cursor will become invalid. For this reason, you do not necessarily need to store the etag at all:

> Cursor-based pagination is the most efficient method of paging and
>   should always be used where possible - a cursor refers to a random
>   string of characters which mark a specific item in a list of data.
>   Unless this item is deleted, the cursor will always point to the same
>   part of the list, but it will be invalidated if an item is removed.
>   Therefore, your app shouldn't assume that store any older cursors, or
>   that they will still be valid.